# Don't know why the function is not returning the exact beverage type

Tags: python

```
def get_beverage_type(a_enabled: bool, b_enabled: bool) -> str:
    """
    Returns the beverage type defined by the switches.
    """
    if a_enabled == "y" == True and b_enabled == "n" == False:
        return "Juice, Orange"
    elif a_enabled == "n" == False and b_enabled == "y" == True:
        return "Milk, 2%"
    else:
        return "Coke, Diet" 
           
Switch_A = (input("Is switch A enabled? (y/n): "))
Switch_B = (input("Is switch B enabled? (y/n): "))

print(f"Result: {get_beverage_type(Switch_A, Switch_B)}")
```

Putting the values as Switch_A = y and and Switch_valueB = n , it still returns Result: Coke, Diet

Comment: No need to add `== True` or `== False`, just remove them.

Comment: If `a_enabled == 'y'` is satisfied, then it will automatically be `True`.

Comment: Your type hinting seems to be off; `a_enabled: bool, b_enabled: bool` implies that these variables are supposed to be booleans, but when you call the function you actually pass strings such as `"y"` or `"n"`.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to believe that `a_enabled == "y" == True` checks if `a_enabled` is one of those values.

That is not what it does. It is equivalent to `a_enabled == "y" and "y" == True` which of course is always `False`.

You probably meant `a_enabled == "y" or a_enabled == True`, for which there is no shorthand. However you can also use `a_enabled in ("y", True)` which is conceptually the same, even if it's technically not equivalent.

Edit: it's also possible that you meant `(a_enabled == "y") == True`, which is simply redundant.

Answer (score 0):

An expression like this:

```
b_enabled == "n" == False
```

looks like a convoluted (and incorrect) way of saying `b_enabled != "n"`, which I don't think is what you want (although if it is, you should just write it that way).  Just remove the `== True` and `== False` stuff and your code does what I *think* you're trying to do:

```
def get_beverage_type(a_enabled: bool, b_enabled: bool) -> str:
    """
    Returns the beverage type defined by the switches.
    """
    if a_enabled == "y" and b_enabled == "n":
        return "Juice, Orange"
    elif a_enabled == "n" and b_enabled == "y":
        return "Milk, 2%"
    else:
        return "Coke, Diet"


print(get_beverage_type("y", "n"))  # Juice, Orange
print(get_beverage_type("n", "y"))  # Milk, 2%
print(get_beverage_type("n", "n"))  # Coke, Diet
print(get_beverage_type("y", "y"))  # Coke, Diet
```

Comment: `b_enabled == "n" == False` is not `b_enabled != "n"`, it is `b_enabled == "n" and "n" == False`, which is always false.

Comment: that's even worse!

Answer (score 0):

```
a_enabled = "y"

if a_enabled == "y" == True:
    print(1)

'''
it means 

a_enabled == 'y' and a_enabled == True . it is carzy.

so you should uese 

'''
if a_enabled == 'y' or a_enabled == True:
    print(1)
```